# How use my data for sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am trying to understand how `Naive Bayes` works and want to create some example using `sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB`.
I have a data:

```
[
[1, 0],
[1, 1],
[0, 1],
// ...
];
```

Where here `[[1, 0]]` the first number is the type of a pet: cat or dog, and the second one: light or dark color has a pet. After that I want to give a list like [0,0,1] that represent a color and predict the type of pet.

And I am trying to use example from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html. I rewrote this:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

To:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([ [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1] ])
```

But what should be instead of `Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])` in my case?

Or maybe I should keep my data in another one format?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Y` should be a one dimensional array of 'class labels'.

For each element in your data set `X`, you'd have one element in `Y` that gives the classification, e.g. `0` for a dog, `1` for a cat.

It looks like you have included the class label as the first element in your `X`, you might want to separate those into `Y`.

Due to the simplicity of the classification and the features of the data set GaussianNB seems to be a bit overkill, but I understand you're just exploring the concept.